How can i update the content of a json file dynamically in android/app/src/main/raw directory
I am using AWS Rekognition feature in my flutter project where i had to put the amplifyconfiguration.json file in the android/app/src/main/raw directory of the project.
the file content is:
{
  "auth": {
    "plugins": {
      "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
        "IdentityManager": {
          "Default": {}
        },
        "CredentialsProvider": {
          "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
              "PoolId": "pool_id_value",
              "Region": "region_value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

The requirement is that when app launches i have to call an API which will provide me the values for PoolId and Region. And then i need to update the values in the amplifyconfiguration.json file.
I have searched it online how can i update the values in the file which resides in the raw directory. But Couldn't find any solution so far. I have been informed that it is impossible to dynamically create or update the content inside the raw directory.
Is it true? Is there any workaround for this problem?

i don't believe you can edit android resources files in the raw/ folder after compilation. If your using a flutter package to manage the AWS Rekognition feature, then i would assume there is a way to manually set these values from the plugin.

There is no flutter plugin available for AWS. So i used method channels to connect with their own native sdk.

As Emile mentioned, I don't think changing value in resource is possible.
How about storing the PoolId and Region in DataStore?

Hey Hyundo! thank you for the answer but i cannot use DataStore because the file needs to be placed inside the raw directory and then their own native sdk automatically fetches the values from that file.
